# How can I extract audio from FLV?

Tags: command-line, audio, ffmpeg, flv, speex

I need to extract the audio from a FLV file recorded using FMS. I used the SPEEX coded in my flash application that streams the audio and video to FMS.

I have tried using FFMPEG, with no luck. This is the -i outputs of my FLV:

**FFmpeg version SVN-rUNKNOWN, Copyright (c) 2000-2007 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-pp --enable-swscaler --enable-pthreads --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libogg --enable-libgsm --enable-dc1394 --disable-debug --enable-shared --prefix=/usr
  libavutil version: 1d.49.3.0
  libavcodec version: 1d.51.38.0
  libavformat version: 1d.51.10.0
  built on Apr 23 2010 15:11:13, gcc: 4.2.4 (Ubuntu 4.2.4-1ubuntu3)
[flv @ 0xb7ed7110]Unsupported audio codec (b)
[flv @ 0xb7ed7110]Unsupported audio codec (b)
Input #0, flv, from 'm.flv':
Duration: 00:00:05.0, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0.0: Video: flv, yuv420p, 288x203, 1000.00 fps(r)
Stream #0.1: Audio: 0x000b, 11025 Hz, mono**

I need a command line utility, since this will be executed from a server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any chance I could have a copy of your FLV?  I am trying to find **any** working example of Speex contained in an FLV, to debug my app.  All the examples I can find are broken.  See [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951523/example-of-a-flv-file-with-speex-encoded-audio).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical flv:

> flv @ 0x152ba80]Estimating duration
>   from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
>   [lavf] stream 0: video (flv), -vid 0
>   [lavf] stream 1: audio (mp3), -aid 0
>   VIDEO:  [FLV1]  320x240  0bpp  25.000
>   fps  250.3 kbps (30.6 kbyte/s)

To read this, ffmpeg must be compiled with additional options:

```
  --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libmp3lame
```

Then,

```
ffmpeg -i flvfile 1.mp3
```

Comment: If I try to extract the audio from a FLV created using any other tool but FMS, it works without changing my FFFMPEG options. The problem is with the FLVs created from live streams and FMS.

Comment: thanks, but how can I recompile FFMPEG if I just installed it using apt-get?

Comment: if I do: sudo apt-get install libspeex, it installs libspeex1. how can a re-compile FFMPEG to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this site: [flv2mp3.com](http://www.flv2mp3.com/)

Update: Sorry, I didn't read the command line part of your question.