# Example of a FLV file with Speex-encoded audio?

Tags: flash, audio, flv, speex

Can anyone point me to an example of a Flash video file with a Speex-encoded soundtrack, freely downloadable from somewhere on the web?

Video can be in any codec (ideally none.)

I am trying to develop an application to generate such a file programmatically and would like a valid example to compare with my output for debugging purposes.

---

[This link](http://trac.perian.org/ticket/428) claims to be Speex in FLV, but it doesn't work in any of the players I tried it in.

---

[This file](https://roundup.libav.org/issue977) is readable but allegedly contains a bug (but I don't know what it is)

Comment: Do you have any speex-encoded audio file that you can post? Or maybe a video file with speex audio in a non-flv container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution could be to generate your own files using a flv muxer. You could try with ffmpeg, it should be something like `ffmpeg -i blah.avi -i blah.mp3 -vcodec copy -acodec copy out.flv`. There is a discussion about this approach (for a different format) [here](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/287201-Mux-a-FLV-AVI-MP3-FLV-with-ffmpeg-or-mencoder).

Answer (score 1):

audio-only-speex.flv over here plays for me: http://streams.videolan.org/issues/2973/